# What is the difference between $\partial_{\mu}$ and $\partial^{\mu}$?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, differentiation, notation

I've seen in many books both expressions $\partial_{\mu}$ and $\partial^{\mu}$, which are the covariant and contravariant partial derivatives, respectively, and in one of Susskind's books he defined them as:

$\partial_{\mu}=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}$

And

$\partial^{\mu}=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}$ if $\mu\neq0$ and $\partial^{0}=-\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^0}$ (only for $\mu=0$).

But that is for Special Relativity, in which we use $\eta_{\mu\nu}$. *Does it goes exactly the same in General Relativity? Or do we have to multiply it by $g_{\mu\nu}$ somewhere?*

From what I've seen in books the Special Relativity and General Relativity are the same, but I'd like confirmation. Is it really that way?

Comment: The way I like to see it, $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}$ is the "regular" gradient with respect to spacetime and $\partial^\mu$ is a shorthand for $g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\nu$. So yes, in general relativity you would have to use the metric tensor.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/346923/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion : Your above comment is essentially an answer. If you don't intend to turn it into an answer, may I 
have your permission to addend an exact copy-paste of it in my (incomplete) answer ?

Comment: @Frobenius Yes feel free to do so

Comment: Thanks a lot @AccidentalTaylorExpansion.

Comment: In a generic semi-Riemannian manifold, $\partial_\mu f$ are the components of the one-form $df$ whereas $\partial^\mu f \equiv g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\nu f$ are the components of the corresponding vector field $\nabla f$ associated to it by the isomorphism between vectors and covectors induced by the metric. The notation is not accidental, this is the proper generalization of the gradient as a vector field to generic manifolds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bl}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}} 
\newcommand{\e}{\bl=}
\newcommand{\p}{\bl+}
\newcommand{\m}{\bl-}
\newcommand{\mb}[1]{\mathbf {#1}}
\newcommand{\mr}[1]{\mathrm {#1}}
\newcommand{\plr}[1]{\left(#1\right)}
\newcommand{\blr}[1]{\left[#1\right]}
\newcommand{\clr}[1]{\left\{#1\right\}}
\newcommand{\vlr}[1]{\left\vert#1\right\vert}
\newcommand{\Vlr}[1]{\left\Vert#1\right\Vert}
\newcommand{\narVlr}[1]{\left|\!\left|#1\right|\!\right|}
\newcommand{\lara}[1]{\left\langle#1\right\rangle}
\newcommand{\lav}[1]{\left\langle#1\right|}
\newcommand{\vra}[1]{\left|#1\right\rangle}
\newcommand{\lavra}[2]{\left\langle#1|#2\right\rangle}
\newcommand{\vp}{\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}}
\newcommand{\x}{\bl\times}
\newcommand{\ox}{\bl\otimes}$

Note the following notation
\begin{equation}
\left.
\begin{cases}
x^\mu \e \plr{x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3}\e \plr{ct,\mr x,\mr y,\mr z}\e \plr{ct,\bl x}\\
x_\mu \e \plr{x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3}\e \plr{ct,\m\mr x,\m\mr y,\m\mr z}\e\plr{ct,\m\bl x}\\
x_\mu \e \eta_{\mu\nu}x^\nu\\
\eta_{\mu\nu}\e \texttt{diag}\plr{\p 1,\m 1,\m 1,\m 1}\\
x_0\e \p x^0,x_1\e \m x^1,x_2\e \m x^2,x_3\e \m x^3\\
\end{cases}\right\}
\boldsymbol{\implies}
\left.
\begin{cases}
\nabla^\mu\e\partial^\mu\e\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_\mu}\e\plr{\dfrac{1}{c}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t},\m\bl\nabla}\\
\nabla_\mu\e \partial_\mu\e\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}\e\plr{\dfrac{1}{c}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial  t},\p\bl\nabla}\\
\square\e\nabla^\mu\nabla_\mu \e\partial^\mu\partial_\mu \e\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_\mu}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}\e \dfrac{1}{c^2}\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\m\nabla^{2}
\end{cases}\right\}
\nonumber  
\end{equation}

The position of the index $\:\mu\:$ is not accidental. The upper index $\:\mu\:$ in $\:\partial^\mu\:$ is due to the fact that $\:\partial^\mu\:$ is a contra-variant 4-vector operator (like the contra-variant position 4-vector $\:x^\mu\:$), while the lower index $\:\mu\:$ in $\:\partial_\mu\:$ is due to the fact that $\:\partial_\mu\:$ is a co-variant 4-vector operator  (like the co-variant position 4-vector $\:x_\mu\:$). That's why the expression
\begin{equation*}
\partial^\mu\partial_\mu \e \dfrac{1}{c^2}\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\m\nabla^{2}
\end{equation*}
is a Lorentz invariant scalar operator (by this  the Lorentz co-variance of the  Klein-Gordon equation is proved). Co-variance of an equation means its form invariance under Lorentz transformations.

---

**ADDENDUM**

To complete my answer I post an exact copy of @AccidentalTaylorExpansion's comment, essentially  an answer, under his/her permission :

> The way I like to see it, $\:\:\partial/\partial x^\mu\:\:$
> is the $^{\prime\prime}$regular$^{\prime\prime}$ gradient with respect to spacetime and $\partial^\mu\:\:$  is a shorthand for $\:\:g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\nu$. So yes, in general relativity you would have to use the metric tensor. – AccidentalTaylorExpansion  Jul 20, 2023 at 11:44

Comment: Wow! Thanks a million for such a detailed comment!

Comment: @Antoniou : Note that the position of the index $\:\mu\:$ is not accidental. The upper index $\:\mu\:$ in $\:\partial^\mu\:$ is due to the fact that $\:\partial^\mu\:$ is a contra-variant 4-vector operator, while the lower index $\:\mu\:$ in $\:\partial_\mu\:$ is due to the fact that $\:\partial_\mu\:$ is a co-variant 4-vector operator. That's why $\:\partial^\mu\partial_\mu\:$ is a Lorentz invariant scalar operator (by this is proved the Lorentz co-variance of the  Klein-Gordon).

Comment: This is a nice answer, and I upvoted it, but the body of the question asked about how this works in GR.

Comment: @Ghoster :  I agree with you. You are absolutely right. I chose not to give a full answer implying that the answer is contained in AccidentalTaylorExpansion's comment which has already been upvoted 9 times as useful. Later on I'll post an ADDENDUM with this answer-comment.